# How to get all aliases for a cmdlet in power shell?

Tags: powershell, alias

How can I get all aliases for a cmdlet? For example `Get-Help` cmdlet has `gcm` and `man`.

I tried `Get-Alias` but it gives unwanted answers. My requirement is to get all the aliases for a particular cmdlet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this info by using `-Definition` parameter:

```
Get-Alias -Definition Get-Help
```

Comment: Get-Alias -Definition Get-Help returns an error, but Get-Alias -Definition help returns man -> help which is a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions (for those who are more familiar with Linux style):

```
alias | findstr Get-Help
```

or

```
Get-Alias | findstr Get-Help
```

or

```
gal | findstr Get-Help
```

where `gal` is an alias for `Get-Alias`.

Answer (score 0):

Some other ways

```
Get-Alias | Where-Object {$_.Definition -eq 'Get-Help' }
gal | where { $_.Definition -eq 'Get-Help' }
Get-ChildItem Alias: | Where-Object { $_.Definition -eq 'Get-Help' }
```